# It seems that JavaScript RegExp isn't finding "leftmost longest"

Tags: javascript, regex

I observe these results:

```
// Test 1:
var re = /a|ab/;
"ab".match(re); // returns ["a"]   <--- Unexpected

// Test 2:
re = /ab|a/;
"ab".match(re); // returns ["ab"]
```

I would expect tests 1 and 2 to both return ["ab"], due to the principal of "leftmost longest".  I don't understand why the order of the 2 alternatives in the regex should change the results.

Comment: A good observation, but I don't see the question.

Comment: @ChrisHayes, My assumption is that "RegExp" should find the "leftmost longest" match.  In Test 1, that would be "ab", which is longer than "a".  But that is not happening.

Comment: @JoelFan it seems like JavaScript does not implement "leftmost longest" and goes with the first subexpression match like Perl

Comment: FYI... Perl seems to act the same way as JavaScript in this respect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because JavaScript doesn't implement the POSIX engine.

> POSIX NFA Engines work similarly to Traditional NFAs with one
>   exception: a POSIX engine always picks the longest of the leftmost
>   matches. For example, the alternation `cat|category` would match the full word "category" whenever possible, even if the first alternative ("cat") matched and appeared earlier in the alternation. (SEE MRE 153-154)

Source: Oreilly - Javascript Pocket Reference, p.4

Comment: Although @Agustin's answer is helpful, I accepted this one because it answers the "why"

Answer (score 3):

Find the reason below:

> Note that alternatives are considered left to right until a match is
>   found. If the left alternative matches, the right alternative is
>   ignored, even if it would have produced a “better” match. Thus, when
>   the pattern /a|ab/ is applied to the string “ab,” it matches only the
>   first letter.

(source: Oreilly - Javascript Pocket Reference - Chapter 9 Regular Expressions)

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, I feel honored to have thought of O'Reilly's question, verbatim even